# Jenkins agent section selection based on parameter value

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Based on pipeline form parameter value, I want to decide whether to run pipeline on VM or docker container hence need to select `agent` section in pipeline accordingly. In order to achieve that tried following -

```
pipeline {
    if(env.mode.equals("docker")) {
        agent {

            docker {
                label 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
                image imagename
                args '--cap-add SYS_ADMIN --cap-add DAC_READ_SEARCH -v $HOME/.m2:/usr/share/.m2 --user root --memory=9g ...
            }

        }
    }

        if(env.mode.equals("vm")) {
            agent {
                label {
                    label 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xx'
                    customWorkspace "<workspace-path>"
                }
            }
        }
    stages {
        ...
    }
}
```

But this fails. Is there any way this can be achieved with Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: Is this declarative or scripted syntax? Both are currently being used in the question.

Comment: It is declarative pipeline